# Help needed in creating a custom shipping module

Tags: module, magento-1, shipping

Good morning all,
I have a little background in php and magento.. I got a store up and running.. but i ran into an issue.. my local shipping company has its own shipping api so i cant use a standard shipping module like fedex or ups or dhl.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to a guide that i can read and learn how to make the shipping module i need to interact with the shipping companys API

Answer (score 1):

Refer following link to create shipping method extension.

1. http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/
2. http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/14/magento-create-custom-shipping-method/
3. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/
4. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Inchoo guys explained in detail in [this blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/).  But it require some modification.

Instead of getExpressRate and standardRate function you have to call the third party API using **Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl** class [for example](http://www.magentodeveloperleedsuk.co.uk/use-curl-with-magento-and-zend-framework/) and extract the data and then set the same in price.